# Calculate sine curve in C

Tags: c, math, trigonometry, curve, degrees

I want to get a periodic value that moves between 0 and a specified height (in my case that's 40) from the sine curve.

But I am messing something up, because my value goes all the way to 79 instead of the expected 40. What am I doing wrong?

This is my attempt:

```
#include <math.h>

    #define degToRad(angleInDegrees) ((angleInDegrees)*M_PI / 180.0)
    
    int main()
    {  
        int height = 40;
        int i = 0;
        while (1) {
    
            int value = height + sin(degToRad(i / 2 + 1)) * height;
            printf("val = %i\n", value);
            i++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you do not want to divide by 2.0 rather than by 2 ? `i / 2` is an integer division

Comment: The sine function fluctuates between −1 and +1. So `height + sin(something) * height` varies between height + −1•height (which is 0) and height + +1•height (which is 2•height). To make the range go from 0 to height, use `(height + sin(something) * height)/2`.

Comment: what about to also stop the loop when *i* reach a given value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct resolution is to divide the wave magnitude by 2 [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430225/calculate-sine-curve-in-c#comment112162030_63430225)

```
// int value = height + sin(degToRad(i / 2 + 1)) * height; 
int value = height + sin(degToRad(i / 2 + 1)) * height)/2;
```

and use floating point math in the `i/2` division. [@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430225/calculate-sine-curve-in-c/63430584#comment112162026_63430225)

---

I expect a more acceptable result using rounding rather than truncation (what OP's code does) going from floating point to `int`.

```
int value = height + lround(sin(degToRad(i / 2 + 1)) * height)/2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The amplitude of the curve would then be `height / 2` and not `height`; simply replace

`int value = height + sin(degToRad(i / 2 + 1)) * height;`

with

`int value = height / 2 + sin(degToRad(i / 2 + 1)) * height / 2;`

A good way to remember that is that sin x is always in the range [-1, 1].